# How can I get snowsql to use multiple clusters for parallel processing?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, scripting, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm having trouble getting snowsql to run multiple queries at once using an autoscaling warehouse that should scale up to 4 clusters.

My goal is to run a group of queries via snowsql and take advantage of autoscaling when one query is not done but another query could begin on another available cluster.

I understand I could use Python to run threads executing queries in parallel, but this seems too complex when Snowflake could have an easier way to manage parallel processing.

This was originally [discussed and answered in the dbt slack](https://getdbt.slack.com/archives/CJN7XRF1B/p1646120510692359?thread_ts=1645827976.560759&cid=CJN7XRF1B).

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was insta-closed and anonymously too, but it is a useful bit that I learned about Snowflake today thanks to users needing and finding this answers. I'm posting it here to help more people in the spirit of https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer. Community with enough points, please vote to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

There's an easy way to run queries asynchronously with the `snowsql` CLI: Just add an `>` after the `;`.

For example, this short script should take 18 seconds to run:

```sql
select current_timestamp(), count(seq4()) from table(generator(timelimit => 3)) v ;>
select current_timestamp(), count(seq4()) from table(generator(timelimit => 3)) v ;>
select current_timestamp(), count(seq4()) from table(generator(timelimit => 3)) v ;>
select current_timestamp(), count(seq4()) from table(generator(timelimit => 3)) v ;>
select current_timestamp(), count(seq4()) from table(generator(timelimit => 3)) v ;>
select current_timestamp(), count(seq4()) from table(generator(timelimit => 3)) v ;>
```

But as each line ends with a `>`, `snowsql` executes them in parallel (all in only 3 seconds).

To examine the results of each query interactively, just ask `snowsql` for `!queries`.

In bash/shell:

```sql
snowsql -q "select current_timestamp(), count(seq4()) from table(generator(timelimit => 3));>
select current_timestamp(), count(seq4()) from table(generator(timelimit => 3));"
```

Read more:

- https://www.snowflake.com/blog/snowsql-interactivity/

Comment: (h/t: Leo Folsom)

Comment: Editing the answer seems to be locked, but just a note that the snowsql version needs `"` at the end, like this:
`snowsql -q "select current_timestamp(), count(seq4()) from table(generator(timelimit => 3));>
select current_timestamp(), count(seq4()) from table(generator(timelimit => 3));"`